# Put reflect.Method to a functional interface

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, method-reference

For example, I have a class with a method

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod(Object arg) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

And I obtained method through reflection in another class:

```
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();

Method method = someClass.class.getMethod();
```

Is there any way to put it to a `Consumer<Object>` and then use with `Consumer.accept()`, or do I have to use something like this:

```
Consumer<Object> consumer = object -> method.invoke(instance, new Object())
```

Comment: What don't you like about your construct (other than using `new Object()` instead of `object` as the argument)?

Comment: It's mostly fine, but I'm really curious about another more elegant or alternative solution. Also, I wanted to know if it's considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Consumer` dynamically:

```
static class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod(Object arg) {
        System.out.println("test" + arg);
    }
}


static Consumer<Object> findConsumer(SomeClass instance) {
    try {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class);

        return (Consumer<Object>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                lookup,
                "accept",
                MethodType.methodType(Consumer.class, SomeClass.class),
                methodType,
                lookup.findVirtual(SomeClass.class, "someMethod", methodType),
                methodType)
                .getTarget()
                .invokeExact(instance);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
Consumer<Object> consumer = findConsumer(new SomeClass());
    consumer.accept("hello world");
```